# Don't understand the tense and context of this sentence

Tags: grammar

I will study hard until I've gotten a high score on this exam.

Wtf does this sentence mean ? It's not in future perfect and it seems like present perfect although I'm not sure (becuase why to use this tense in this sentence it doesn't make sense ).

Why not to use future perfect - I will have studied hard until I get a high score on this exam or just the present/future simple (like a fact ) - I will study hard until I get a high score on this exam .

Could you guys break down the sentece so I can understand it?.. thanks

Comment: The sentence makes it sound as if you can keep retaking the exam. You should study hard until you're prepared. "I will study hard until I'm confident for the exam." Or get a high score for the exam. You're right, this sentence is quite incomprehensible, where did you find it?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62627/until-perfect-present-present

Comment: Yes… what did Nethan's link leave unclear, please?

Either way, does it not become more clear if you simply drop the irrelevant "hard" and "on this exam"?

Does "I will study until I've gotten a high score" make no more sense to you?

Comment: Uh… apart from the actual Question, what to you is the difference between "Wtf" and "what"?